# How i can apply a background image to the body of only ONE Component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a main component on every page, which is Navbar, and I have another component, which is a page to contact us. I want to make a background for a component that contact us, but it does not affect the Navbar? Also, if I give body tag the background image, all the other components will take the same background as the photo cuz i give it to the body! what i can do in this case?

Comment: Add a class to the contact us component and add `background-image` to that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap each component in a different div.

```
<div>
 Navbar
</div>

<div style={{backgroundColor: 'color here'}}>
 Contact us
</div>
```

Style inside the div or add a className and style in a separate file with CSS:

```
<div className="yourClass">
 Contact us
</>
```

and in a separate .css file:

```
.yourClass {
 background-color: 'color name';
}
```